# Connect to SQL Server Windows Authentication using DBeaver

Tags: sql-server, dbeaver, runas

Currently, I'm using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to connect to remote SQL Server.
And we are using command-line to connect to that server.

```
$ path\to\runas.exe /netonly /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME "path\to\Ssms.exe -S ip.xxx.yyy.zzz"
```

How can I connect to the same remote database using DBeaver ? I kept getting

```
Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

Other info :

1. Authentication method : Windows Authentication
2. SQL Server Version : 12.0.5000 SP2
3. DBeaver Version : 6.2.2.x
4. There is a prompt for password when we use the command-line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For DBeaver, you may need to do the same thing as well into something like this :

```
$ path\to\runas.exe /netonly /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\DBeaver\dbeaver.exe -nl en"
```

Then, from DBeaver New Connection change the SQL Server authentication to Windows Authentication. It will use the username that we pass from runas.

Comment: Is there a way use `runas` in a shell command before you connect with the built in DBeaver tools?

Comment: you can run `path\to\runas.exe /netonly /user:DOMAIN\USERNAME cmd`. It will open a new cmd prompt. Any command run in there will use this domain username. Not sure if this is want you want though.